# Aligning a checkbox next to a <td> in html

Tags: html, css, html-table, margin

I have a basic CSS/html question about using html/CSS. I thought this was fairly basic and obvious, however it is not working as intended.

[image: http://puu.sh/2LuHq.png]

In this basic image, I would want the Labels to be to the right of Expertise

(creating a registration page where the user selects their Expertise)

I would believe this is basically

```
 <tr>

 <td>Expertise</td>
  <input type="checkbox" style="vertical-align: left; margin: 12px;"> Label </input><br>            
  <input type="checkbox" style="vertical-align: left; margin: 12px;"> Label 2 </input>

</tr>
```

however this is not working as intended.

Comment: why can't you put that two checkboxes before td ends

Comment: Just switch them. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GxkFS/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all your markup is invalid, `table` element can only have elements which are meant for `table` as their child elements i.e `tbody, thead, th, tr, td` etc, and no other elements, instead you can place those checkboxes inside `td`

Secondly input tag doesn't have any explicit closing tag, you need to self close it, else leave it without closing just like `<br>`

Third - Use `label` tag instead of having stray text besides checkbox

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DawZK/)

The right way

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="valign">
        Expertise
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" style="vertical-align: left; margin: 12px;" />
        <label>Label</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" style="vertical-align: left; margin: 12px;" />
        <label>Labe2</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.valign {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: is there any reason for my labels to be way off like http://puu.sh/2Lvcu.png instead of the way I want it in the jfiddle

Comment: @JavaChipMocha Yes, I'll show you a benifit of using them wait

Comment: @JavaChipMocha Select the text and checkboxes will be selected automatically :) http://jsfiddle.net/DawZK/1/ also it's better to have labels instead of stray text, labels will show that yes, this text belongs to that particular checkbox

Comment: the problem I also had was, instead of using <table> I was using this particular css http://jsfiddle.net/j4z9w/. an additional question would be how would I incorporate this, or should I just edit it.

Comment: @JavaChipMocha Scrap that and start with fresh, am damn sure it's not you who has written that piece of code

Comment: yes, but for the purpose, I understand how the child works because I was using the form across all the pages. However, scrapping that breaks the format for the input fields afterwards. Is there a way to workaround this, sort of like creating an exception?

Comment: @JavaChipMocha Learn CSS and HTML :) best way to go for it

Comment: I am trying my best! I think I will just create a new form but try to figure out what's causing the odd spacing and just remove that? right idea? thank you for the help anyway!

Comment: @JavaChipMocha Will help you for basic form :) wait

Comment: I am getting http://puu.sh/2Lw9p.png
when my code is http://jsfiddle.net/j4z9w/3/
any ideas why?

Comment: remove this first `vertical-align: left; margin: 12px;` and also `width: 300px;` from `#formTable tr td input`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using tables, just place the input tags into another td tag like this:

```
<tr>

 <td>Expertise</td>
 <td>
  <input type="checkbox" style="vertical-align: left; margin: 12px;"> Label </input><br>            
  <input type="checkbox" style="vertical-align: left; margin: 12px;"> Label 2 </input>
 </td>

</tr>
```

This will make the checkboxes appear to the right of "Expertise".